# Как добавить значение в Python Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Загружаю распарсенный текст в Enum. От 20 до 6733 элементов.

```
    >>> attributes = Enum('Attr', {'Known': 123})
    >>> attributes(123)
    <Attr.Known: 123>
```

Хочу чтоб при непопадании выводился элемент того же класса, но без имени или автоматом сгенерированным именем.

```
    >>> attributes(256)
    <Attr.Unknown: 256>
```

При попытке переопределить *missing* не смог подсунуть значение.

Comment: Пример бы более подробный для воспроизведения.

Comment: добавил пример, хотя уже нашел ответ

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
import aenum

class Enum(aenum.Enum):
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(self, value):
        aenum.extend_enum(self, f"Unknown.{value}", value)
        return self(value)
```